# I'm trying to keep my nav links in place on a small screen, they disapear at 900px

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to keep my nav links visible I tried a drop down button that would not drop down... I installed popper js it still didn't.

I took the button out because I more likely just want the links horizontally on screen. Is that possible?

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top ">  

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">    
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-4">
     <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" data-value="home" href="#home">Home</a>        
  </li>  
      <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-value="about" href="#about">About</a>        
  </li>  
     <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link " data-value="photography"href="#photography">Photography</a>    
 </li>
     <li class="nav-item"> 
     <a class="nav-link " data-value="blog" href="#casestudies">Case Studies</a>         
</li>   
     <li class="nav-item">  
     <a class="nav-link " data-value="team" href="#projects"> Projects</a>       
</li>  
    <li class="nav-item"> 
    <a class="nav-link " data-value="contact" href="#">Contact</a>       
</li> 
    </ul> 
  
    </div>
  
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this nav bar...

[BootStrap Navbar W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar&stacked=h)